# What is a particular use of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gram-schmidt

We have a linear space *V* of $m \times n$ matrices. I know that we can use Gram-Schmidt to construct an orthonormal basis, but the natural basis for this space (where every *ij*-th element is $1$ and the rest $0$) is just that - every matrix there is orthogonal to the rest, and each norm equals $1$.

Where does the algorithm come into use? Why would somebody go through the trouble of constructing a new basis when the natural one fits the bill?

Comment: The "natural" (I assume that you mean obvious in this case) may not necessarily be orthonormal in whatever inner product we're working with at the time. However, the "natural" basis does has an advantage! We can make use of the fact that the inner product is a bilinear map, so calculating the inner product for the "natural" basis (choose a clever one) will vastly reduce on our calculations when performing the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: I'd add as an example that for example polynomials have $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ as a "natural basis", but with regards to the usual $L^2$ inner product over an interval, this isn't an orthonormal basis at all. In fact, one can construct Legendre polynomials by G-S orthogonalizing that basis.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where the linear space $V$ is a sub-space of a larger space $W$. Using Gram-Schmidt, we can construct an orthonormal basis of $V$, without leaving $V$, i.e. not involving any vectors $W \setminus V$. There might not be a canonical basis of $V$ at all.

One applications are orthonormal bases of Eigenspaces of symmetric matrices. Eigenspaces to different eigenvectors are orthonormal to each other, but within one space, one needs to do something if you want to have an orthonormal basis of the whole space.

As a more concrete example: What's the 'natural' or canonical basis of $\operatorname{span}\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Harville's "Matrix Algebra from a Statistician's Perspective" and he doesn't mention this use. Can you recommend a book where I can read up more on Eigenspaces and such uses of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Gram Schmidt in order to obtain decomposition of a matrix $A \in \Re^{n\times m}, n>m$ as:
\begin{align}
QR = A \quad Q \in \Re^{n \times n},R \in \Re^{n \times m}
\end{align}
where $Q$ is orthogonal matrix obtained by Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation and $R$ is right upper matrix with zero raws $r_i$ for $i > m$ . Espacially you can use it decomposition in order to solve minimalisation problem of the form:
\begin{align}
\min \limits_{x \in \Re^m \setminus \{0\}} ||Ax-b ||_2 ,\quad b \in \Re^n
\end{align}